# Tish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also left Mitzrayim בחצי הלילה which = 190

When we left we took along הכסף והזהב which = 190

We left to eventually reach כנען which = 190

Answer (score 4):

190 is the *gimatriya* of קדמא ואזלא and also of קץ, both allusions (I forget where I've seen them) to the 190 years fewer the Jews were in Egypt than promised.

Comment: The GR"A, maybe?

Comment: Consider checking commentaries on the line in the Haggada חישב את הקץ

Answer (score 3):

190 years after Yitzchok was born, Yaakov arrived in Mitzrayim.

Answer (score 2):

[Reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=jsSVv73IySEC&pg=PA361&dq=sadly), 190 Jews were arrested during [the escape by sea from Denmark to Sweden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_of_the_Danish_Jews#The_deportation_order_and_rescue).